# Cant resolve why its not recognising express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code, express-router

For the below code

```
import pkg from 'express';
const { express } = pkg;
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

import { Connection } from './database/db.js';
import router from './routes/route.js';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();  

app.use('/', router)

const PORT = 4000;

app.listen(PORT,() =>{

    console.log(`server is running on port: ${PORT}`)

});

//parse the importted usrname and password
Connection(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

I tried imprting express using pkg import as required in latest import and added "type":modeule in package.json
But the server is not recogninsing express as a function due to I'm having problem to use app.use() as well as it is also causing error in recogninsing

for router.js code is

```
import pkg from 'express';
const { express } = pkg;

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/signup',signupUser);

export default router;
```

Can you please suggest where I can i Do?

Answer (score 0):

Server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import cors from 'cors'
import connectDB from './database/db.js'
import adminRoutes from './admin/routes/adminRoutes.js'
dotenv.config()
connectDB()
const app = express()

const router = express.Router()
app.use(cors())
app.use('/api/', routes)
const PORT = 5000

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`
  )
)
```

Router.js

```
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router()
router.post('/testApi', testApi)


export default router
```

Comment: New es syntax doesn't allow import express as 'express'

Comment: import pkg from 'express';
const { express } = pkg;  remove this line . i give full code.